# Copying a list of modified files from multiple source directories to equivalent destination directory

Tags: vb.net

I am learning VB.NET and writing a utility to copy only the modified files from a preset selection of folders to their equivalent in a backup directory.

For example: D:\Profiles\Mail to E:\Backup\Profiles\Mail

I can already do the copy simply with the following:

```
For Each item In MAILp
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(MAILp, MAILd, True)
    Next
```

But the idea is count the amount of modified files to be copied, and display this all through a progress bar and the background worker (eventually)

At the moment i am working with this;

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Contants for whole activity
    Dim lstFiles As New List(Of FileInfo)
    Dim fsInfo As FileSystemInfo

    'Constants for dirInfo's
    Dim dirInfoMAILp As New DirectoryInfo(MAILp)
    Dim dirInfoDESKTOPp As New DirectoryInfo(DESKTOPp)

    'Loop for Mail
    For Each fsInfo In dirInfoMAILp.GetFileSystemInfos

        Dim strDestFileName As String = Path.Combine(MAILd, fsInfo.Name)
        Dim destFileInfo As New FileInfo(strDestFileName)

        If fsInfo.LastWriteTime > destFileInfo.LastWriteTime Then

            lstFiles.Add(fsInfo)

        End If
    Next

    'Loop for Desktop
    For Each fsInfo In dirInfoDESKTOPp.GetFileSystemInfos

        Dim strDestFileName As String = Path.Combine(DESKTOPd, fsInfo.Name)
        Dim destFileInfo As New FileInfo(strDestFileName)

        If fsInfo.LastWriteTime > destFileInfo.LastWriteTime Then

            lstFiles.Add(fsInfo)

        End If
    Next

    'Number of files to copy
    Label1.Text = lstFiles.Count

 For Each file As FileInfo In lstFiles
        System.IO.File.Copy(file.FullName, DESTINATIONMAIN + file.Name, True)
    Next

End Sub
```

My problem is in three parts:

*1.* If the files do not already exist in the destination, it will throw and exception. This is not good if the utility is being used for the first time. How can I use an ELSE in the loop to copy the file if it doesn't exist in the destination?

*2.* The copy does not copy folders, only files, can I expand it to include folders? Ideally the differential check loop targets the Top folder then goes through every sub folder and file, adding it to the list.

*3.* When copied to the destination folder, the files are copied to the destination top folder "E:\Backup\Profiles", rather than in the sub-folders they were copied from.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: " I cannot work out how to use the lstFiles items to copy from their source directories to their corresponding destination directories." -- can you elaborate?  What are you trying to do with `lstFiles`?  How is it not working?

Comment: Hi - yes, I am trying a loop with the following code:

`For Each File In lstFiles
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(File, DESTINATIONMAIN, True)
        Next`
Where `DESTINATIONMAIN` is E:\Backup\Profiles\. It throws an exception: _Conversion from type 'FileInfo' to type 'String' is not valid_

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean to explain in the comments.  Please update the question itself to make it clearer.